# Displaying the image from this specific url

Tags: android, android-glide

I can't retrieve the image from this particular url to display it using Glide on android. ( http://tnm5.ma/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/11juin.jpg)

any other link I tried, with different format worked but not this one. I also tried with Picasso framework. Nothing

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scrim_layout);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    Glide.with(this).load("http://tnm5.ma/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/11juin.jpg").into(imageView);

}
```

I got no error messages. just not displaying

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem why the image is not loading, it throws a runtime exception as given below

> java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to tnm5.ma not permitted

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)

> Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Therefore you must set the property `android:usesCleartextTraffic` to `true`

`android:usesCleartextTraffic`

> Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default value for apps that target API level 27 or lower is "true". Apps that target API level 28 or higher default to "false".

To solve the problem, use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside the `application tag` in your manifest

```xml
<application
     ...
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     ...>
     ...
</application>
```

Comment: It didn't work either. What I noticed though is that I can't opn the HTTP link but rather the HTTPS ones. So I found a HTTPS link to the picture.